# SwiftUi ARKit measurements

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Sorry I am pretty inexperienced with ARKit. I am working on an app and it will have more features later but the first step would basically be recreating the measure app that is included with iOS. I have looked at the documentation that Apple gives and most of it is for stuff like face tracking, object detection, or image tracking. I wasn't sure exactly where to start. The rest of the existing code I have now is written in SwiftUI if that matters. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, while asking on stackoverflow people usually have something at hand (error, problem, or more or less specific question). Go ahead and try out different things and come back if you get stuck on something. A good place to start are books written by Apple developers especially "App Development with Swift", 2019 has a chapter on ARKit that will help you to start

Answer (score 1):

Understand that it can be quite confusing in the beginning. I would recommend to walk throught the toruial at [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/378-augmented-reality-and-arkit-tutorial). [This toturial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3xFpRWZEz8) from Codestars on Youtube is also very good if you like to listen and watch instead of reading. Both talks go throught a lot of important parts of ARKit so I really recomend it. After that you problably have a create understanding and you clould watch Apples WWDC2019 talk [What's new in ARKit 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/604/).

Hope I understood your question correctly and please reach out if you have any questions or other concerns.